# Limit multivariable calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to find the limit:
\begin{align}
    \lim_{(x,y)\mapsto(0,0)} (x+y)\sin(\frac{1}{x})\sin(\frac{1}{y}).
\end{align}
I have plotted it and evidently it does not exist. I have tried to prove it by finding two different trajectories where the limit is different, but I have not managed to do so. I think it is probably with logarithmic or exponential functions, or maybe it is much simpler than that. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: You couldn't find two such paths because they don't exist. The limit exists; think squeeze theorem

Comment: Proper notation is $(x,y)\to(0,0),$ not $(x,y)\mapsto(0,0).$ That other arrow is used for such things as pointing out that the function $x\mapsto (x+2y)^2$ differs from the function $y\mapsto(x+2y)^2,$ and for referring to one such function.

Comment: The essential fact here is that $\sin(1/x)$ and $\sin(1/y)$ always remain between $-1$ and $+1,$ so that $\left| \sin(1/x) \sin(1/y)\right|\le 1. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

As suggested by @peek-a-boo, you can proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
0 < \left|(x+y)\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\right|\leq |x + y|
\end{align*}

Now you can apply the squeeze theorem as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$.

Can you take it from here?